# AttributeError: 'table__n_a_m_e' object has no attribute 'getBestFullName' error on fpdf2

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, pyfpdf

I am tring to run the example code from fpdf2 [pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Unicode.html](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Unicode.html). It gives me the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "fpdf2.py", line 12, in 
> pdf.add_font('DejaVu', fname='DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf')
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1916, in add_font
> "name": re.sub("[ ()]", "", font["name"].getBestFullName()),
> AttributeError: 'table__n_a_m_e' object has no attribute 'getBestFullName'

I have installed the DejaVuSansCondensed font on my system. I couldn't figure out the error it gives me.
Here is the code.

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

# Add a DejaVu Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
# Supports more than 200 languages. For a coverage status see:
# http://dejavu.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dejavu/trunk/dejavu-fonts/langcover.txt
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', fname='DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf')
pdf.set_font('DejaVu', size=14)

text = u"""
English: Hello World
Greek: Γειά σου κόσμος
Polish: Witaj świecie
Portuguese: Olá mundo
Russian: Здравствуй, Мир
Vietnamese: Xin chào thế giới
Arabic: مرحبا العالم
Hebrew: שלום עולם
"""

for txt in text.split('\n'):
    pdf.write(8, txt)
    pdf.ln(8)

# Add a Indic Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
# Supports: Bengali, Devanagari, Gujarati, 
#           Gurmukhi (including the variants for Punjabi) 
#           Kannada, Malayalam, Oriya, Tamil, Telugu, Tibetan
pdf.add_font('gargi', fname='gargi.ttf')
pdf.set_font('gargi', size=14)
pdf.write(8, u'Hindi: नमस्ते दुनिया')
pdf.ln(20)

# Add a AR PL New Sung Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
# The Open Source Chinese Font (also supports other east Asian languages)
pdf.add_font('fireflysung', fname='fireflysung.ttf')
pdf.set_font('fireflysung', size=14)
pdf.write(8, u'Chinese: 你好世界\n')
pdf.write(8, u'Japanese: こんにちは世界\n')
pdf.ln(10)

# Add a Alee Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
# General purpose Hangul truetype fonts that contain Korean syllable 
# and Latin9 (iso8859-15) characters.
pdf.add_font('eunjin', fname='Eunjin.ttf')
pdf.set_font('eunjin', size=14)
pdf.write(8, u'Korean: 안녕하세요')
pdf.ln(20)

# Add a Fonts-TLWG (formerly ThaiFonts-Scalable) (uses UTF-8)
pdf.add_font('waree', fname='Waree.ttf')
pdf.set_font('waree', size=14)
pdf.write(8, u'Thai: สวัสดีชาวโลก')
pdf.ln(20)

# Select a standard font (uses windows-1252)
pdf.set_font('helvetica', size=14)
pdf.ln(10)
pdf.write(5, 'This is standard built-in font')

pdf.output("unicode.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue.
Since this question ist still quite new, here's what I did to solve it:

**First, note:** the problem seems to be a known bug in fpdf2, stemming from the introduction of the library `fonttools` starting with `fpdf2 v2.5.7`.

https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2/issues/524

So i uninstalled `fonttools` and `fpdf2`, then reinstalled a different version of `fpdf2`:

```
pip install fpdf2==2.4.6
```

Now, the AttributeError is gone.

Comment: This worked perfectly. And also I had to pass uni=True value to add_font() method then it work like a charm. Thank you